# How could i access the id of element on whose class emojionearea is being append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, emojione

I am using [emojionearea](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea) in my input type based on class name. For submitting the data with AJAX I need to send the `id` of the input type. When I tried to use `$(this).attr('id');` to get the id it says `undefined`.

Please explain how can access the `id` with help of `$(this)`, because there are more than 1 fields and the id is being generated dynamically .

I have also tried to access the id with `$(this).prev().attr('id');`, `$(this).parent().attr('id');` etc.

Thanks in advance

```js
$(".emojionearea").emojioneArea({
  pickerPosition: "right",
  tonesStyle: "bullet",
  hidePickerOnBlur: true,
  events: {
    keyup: function(editor, event) {
      this.hidePicker()
      if (event.which == 13) {
        var reciver_id = id;
        var message = editor.html();

        if (message != '' || message != 'undefined') {
          request = $.ajax({
            url: "/send-message",
            type: "POST",
            'async': false,
            data: {
              'message': message,
              'reciver_id': reciver_id,
              '_token': CSRF_TOKEN
            },
          });

          request.done(function(res) {
            if (res) {
              editor.html('');
              var text = 'text';
              // ths.parent().parent().children().find('.chat-scroll').append(element);
              $(this).find('.classname').append(text);
            }
          });

          request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: There's no reference to `attr('id')` in the code you've shown...? Also, remove `async: false` as it's very bad practice, and not necessary here.

Comment: <input type="text" id="id to be accessed'" class="emojionearea" name="text" placeholder="Send a message">

Comment: That's the HTML of the input. I asked how and where you're using `attr('id')` in the JS.

Comment: this is the input type where emojionearea append there <div>

Comment: Yes but it's not the information we need. You've stated in the question that `$(this).attr('id');`, `$(this).prev().attr('id');` and `$(this).parent().attr('id');` do not work for you, *yet the JS code doesn't actually show you using them*. At a guess, try `editor.id`

Comment: if(event.which == 13) {
 var reciver_id   = $(this).prev().attr( "id" );
    var message = editor.html();
}

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan for your suggestion.this is the which worked for me:-
editor.parent().prev().attr('id')